# 3D Collision Detection in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, 3d, collision-detection, xna-4.0

I have been searching the web for quite some time about this but I couldn't find anything that's concrete enough to help me out. I know XNA is going to die, but there is still use for it (in my heart, before I port it later to SharpDX)

I'm making a 3D FPS shooter in XNA 4.0 and I am having serious issues on setting up my collision detection.

First of all, I am making models in blender and I have a high polygon and low polygon version of the model. I would like to use the low polygon model with collision detection but I'm baffled as to how to do it. I want to use JigLibX but I'm not sure how to set my project up in order to do so.

In a nutshell: I want to accomplish this one simple goal:
Make a complicated map in blender, and have boundingboxes be made from it and then use a quadtree to split it up. Then my main character and his gun can run around it shooting stuff!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what your concrete question is, but I assume you want to know how to implement collision detection efficiently in principal:

- for characters: use (several) bounding-boxes and bounding spheres (like a sphere for the head, and 9 boxes for torso, legs and arms.
- for terrain: use data from height-map for Y (up/down) collision detection and bounding-boxes/spheres for objects on terrain (like trees, walls, bushes, ...)
- for particles - like gunfire: use points, small bounding spheres or - even better because framerateindependant - raytraycing.

In almost **no case** you want to do collision detection on a polygon-basis as you suggested in your post (quote "low poly modell for collision detection").

I hope that put you in the right direction.

cheers